# How to use WHERE BETWEEN and WHERE simultaneously in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

I am trying to use **where** and **between** at once

```
SELECT 
SUM ((`gen-acute-sales-after-returns`) + SUM(`gen-chronic-sales-after- returns`)) 
  AS `totalGenericSales` ,
(SUM (`eth-acute-sales-after-returns`) + SUM(`eth-chronic-sales-after-returns`)+SUM(`others-sales-after-returns`))
AS `totalEthicalSales` 
FROM `sales` WHERE `date-s` BETWEEN '2018-09-27' AND '2018-11-27' 
WHERE `sales-store-id` = '4'
```

the problem is that if I use **WHERE** `sales-store-id`

or

**WHERE** `date-s` **BETWEEN** '2018-09-27' **AND**  '2018-11-27'

it is working fine,but when I use both at once it is giving syntax error

> Unhandled rejection Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE `sales-store-id` = '4''

what's going on can someone please explain me ?

Comment: Hint:  `AND` not two `WHERE`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't specify `Where` twice if you want to have multiple conditions simultaneously. You use `And`/`Or` [Logical operator(s)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/logical-operators.html) instead.

```
SELECT 
  SUM ((`gen-acute-sales-after-returns`) + SUM(`gen-chronic-sales-after- returns`)) 
  AS `totalGenericSales` ,
  (SUM (`eth-acute-sales-after-returns`) + SUM(`eth-chronic-sales-after-returns`) + SUM(`others-sales-after-returns`))
  AS `totalEthicalSales` 
FROM `sales` 
WHERE `date-s` BETWEEN '2018-09-27' AND '2018-11-27' 
AND `sales-store-id` = '4' /* use AND here instead of WHERE */
```

Answer (score 1):

This query is if you want AND sales store id to be 4:

```
SELECT SUM((`gen-acute-sales-after-returns`) + SUM(`gen-chronic-sales-after- returns`))
    AS `totalGenericSales`,
       (SUM(`eth-acute-sales-after-returns`) + SUM(`eth-chronic-sales-after-returns`) +
        SUM(`others-sales-after-returns`))
    AS `totalEthicalSales`
FROM `sales`
WHERE `date-s` BETWEEN '2018-09-27' AND '2018-11-27'
    AND `sales-store-id` = '4'
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use AND to continue with your query.

```
SELECT 
SUM ((`gen-acute-sales-after-returns`) + SUM(`gen-chronic-sales-after- returns`)) 
AS `totalGenericSales` ,
(SUM (`eth-acute-sales-after-returns`) + SUM(`eth-chronic-sales-after- 
returns`)+SUM(`others-sales-after-returns`))
AS `totalEthicalSales` 
FROM `sales` WHERE `date-s` BETWEEN '2018-09-27' AND '2018-11-27' 
AND `sales-store-id` = 4
```